# Cannot convert value of type error

Tags: swift3

I need help debugging this error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'PHContentEditingInput, [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void' to expected argument type '(PHContentEditingInput?, [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void'
```

Here is the code:

```
asset?.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: {(_ contentEditingInput: PHContentEditingInput, _ info: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void in
 self.storageRef.child(filePath).putFile(imageFile, metadata: metadata, completion: {(_ metadata: FIRStorageMetadata, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
  if error != nil {
   return
  }
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `?` after the `PHContentEditingInput` in completion block of `contentEditingInput` because it is of optional type.

```
asset?.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: 
{(_ contentEditingInput: PHContentEditingInput?, _ info: [AnyHashable: Any]) -> Void in

    self.storageRef.child(filePath).putFile(imageFile, metadata: metadata, completion: {(_ metadata: FIRStorageMetadata, _ error: Error?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
    })
})
```